# How to unregister/delete a slash command in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using **Discord.js V13 (Node JS v16.8.0)** and wanted to delete all registered global commands, I'm using the **@discordjs/rest** module, but I'm not sure how

Here is my deploy-commands.js file:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, turns out you need to put this line of code in between the async function

```
await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), {
    body: commands,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete all global commands, use `Client.application.commands.set()` and pass an empty array

```js
client.application.commands.set([])
```

Comment: where do I input this line of code? in the index.js file or deploy-commands.js file? I assume the index.js file since client is not defined in the other file.

Comment: It's kinda like a one-time code. What I mean by this is that you only have to run it once for it to work. After that, remove the line of code.  And yes you would probably put it in your `index.js` file. Since it's a global command, it will make up to 1 hour to have changes take effect.

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'commands')` when I do `client.application.commands.set([])`

Comment: The client needs to be logged in at the time

Comment: Just to add to this, make sure your client is logged in. I recommend putting it inside of your `ready` event listener.